# Qt Object deleted but signal is not disconnected

Tags: c++, qt

In this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10570857/are-signals-in-qt-automatically-disconnected-when-one-of-the-class-is-deleted) it told when a qobject deleted its active connections will be deleted. I have a case like below:

```
Work* work = new Work();//->Work derived from QObject 
Worker* worker  = new Worker(work);//->Worker derived from QThread and has the ownership of work

connect(work, SIGNAL(percentageComplete(int)), progressDialog, SLOT(setValue(int)));
connect(worker, SIGNAL(finished()),  worker, SLOT(deleteLater()));

progressDialog->show();
worker->start();
```

In worker's destructor I have :

```
Worker::~Worker(void){
    if(work != nullptr){
        work->deleteLater();
    }
}
```

I am %100 sure that work is deleted. I can see it with a breakpoint. I can even see QObjects desctructor call.

But some how deleted work object still receiving signal "percentage complete". And because it is deleted ,causing a crush.

I want to ask why signals are not disconnected even object is deleted?

A second question in Worker's destructor `work->deleteLater();` or `delete work;`  is correct?

Comment: You should provide a minimal working example.

Comment: `deleteLater()` should be used to defer deletion of an object because it might still be needed - e.g. when you want to delete an object inside it's own slot.

Comment: "But some how deleted work object still receiving signal "percentage complete" - Please clarify what you exactly see, add the code where it crashes and add a backtrace maybe. In your code, the work object is *emitting* percentageComplete, not receiving it. Signal/slot connections are destructed if the sender or the receiver are destroyed, so I don't see how your deleted worker can emit a signal. And in your case, delete should be the right thing.

Comment: Please re-read your own question, it doesn't seem to make sense. Why would `work` receive `it's own `percentageCompleted` signal? Also, I suspect you are doing threading somehow wrong. If you are using `QObject` instances in threading, then most likely you should not override `QThread`.

Comment: All you guys were right , reading my own question really helped. Problem was totally different and related with lamdba were not disconnecting automatically. Now what should I do with my question? How should I edit it to make something useful or at least not confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why dont you use [disconnect()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#disconnect) for disconnect all connected slots/signals ?
You can call this function in destructor.[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10570857/are-signals-in-qt-automatically-disconnected-when-one-of-the-class-is-deleted?lq=1) you have solution from similar topic

Comment: That disconnects all connections to signals of that object, not all signals connecting to slots of that object, which is what is required here.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the work object is moved to the worker thread, and that the signal emitted will end up on the event loop, which can be delivered a bit later. Probably you have killed progressDialog at that point.

Answer (score 0):

Until unless you have some custom code, just use `QThread`directly.

```
Work* work = new Work(); // no parent
QThread* thread = new QThread();

work->moveToThread(worker);

connect(thread, SIGNAL(started()), work, SLOT(doSomeWork())); // add this function doSomething() in Work class which on completion should emit finished() signal
connect(work, SIGNAL(finished()), thread, SLOT(quit())); // quit the thread
connect(work, SIGNAL(finished()), work, SLOT(deleteLater())); // delete work after job done
connect(thread, SIGNAL(finished()), thread, SLOT(deleteLater())); // delete thread

// if you are using c++11, do this to see Work and Thread deletion
connect(work, &Work::destroyed, [](){ qDebug() << "Work object deleted"; });
connect(thread, &QThread::destroyed, [](){ qDebug() << "Thread deleted"; });

// start the thread now
thread->start();
```

[See here for more info on QThread usage](https://mayaposch.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-really-truly-use-qthreads-the-full-explanation/)

Answer (score 0):

This happens because there are two threads attempting to use `Work` at the same time, with no apparent synchronization, with predictably bad results.

You have to marshal the ownership of and access to `Work` between the main thread and the worker thread, so that the two threads can't access it at the same time in an unsafe manner.

The destructor of `Worker` is not executed in the `Worker` thread! Furthermore, I don't see any code that prevents that destructor from running while the `Worker` **thread** is still active. Note that a `QThread` is not a *thread*, but a **thread handle**. It's a deceptive name.

Alas, your question can't be answered without seeing a **complete** example that reproduces the issue.