# QT: Should I disconnect slot manually? If yes, how can I disconnect a specific slot?

Tags: c++, qt, signals, slots

I have a slot in class B which will connect to signal in class A, but class B will be deconstructed inconstantly, so during class B's deconstruction, should I disconnect the slot or will it be disconnected by QT? If I should manually disconnect the connection, how can I do it?

Comment: If an object is destroyed and is part of some connection, Qt will take care of the disconnection.

Comment: Having some code here might help, showing `A` and `B` and their connection. Have you tried using the return value of [`connect`](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.5/qobject.html#connect) to `disconnect`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are signals in Qt automatically disconnected when one of the class is deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10570857/are-signals-in-qt-automatically-disconnected-when-one-of-the-class-is-deleted)

Answer (score 1):

Qt takes care of disconnection. You don't have to worry about it.

But it's recommended to use

`obj->deleteLater();`

method rather than

`delete obj;`

[Same Question Exists](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10570876/3421515)

Answer (score 0):

You can catch the signal [void QObject::destroyed(QObject * obj = 0)](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qobject.html#destroyed) to do some clean-up:

> This signal is emitted immediately before the object `obj` is
>   destroyed, and can not be blocked.
>
> All the objects's children are destroyed immediately after this signal
>   is emitted.

To answer:

> should I disconnect the slot or will it be disconnected by QT? If I
>   should manually disconnect the connection, how can I do it?

A signal-slot connection is removed when either of the objects involved are destroyed.

Answer (score -1):

If you are not using thread you can disconnected another class slot like below code here:
 You will call within constructor of A class not outside of constructor

```
bttnShutdown = new QPushButton(this);
bttnShutdown->setGeometry(290, 2, 25, 26);
myWorker =new B;
connect(bttnShutdown, SIGNAL(clicked()), myWorker, SLOT(dowork()));
```

Comment: What does this have to do with the question? There is nothing about threads mentioned in the question.